# Как правильно обрабатывать и выводить ответ от ajax файла и вставлять этот ответ в div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Учу js, выдумываю задачи, зациклилась на одной, очень хочется послушать знающий людей)) Есть форма с одним полем ввода - промокод. Ввожу промокод и кликаю на кнопку "Активировать промокод". Вот как выглядит форма. В этой форме есть строка `<div class="messages_promo"></div>` вот между этими div есть желание вывести ответ от ajax файла. Вроде делаю так, как надо (но это на мой взгляд новичка), но ответ не появляется.

```
<div class="ta-c">
    <h3 class="promo-title light">Введите свой промокод</h3>
        <form action="" class="promo-form">
        <input type="text" name="promo" id="promocod" class="promo-input" placeholder="____" maxlength="4" >
        <div class="promo-text"></div>
        <button class="button js-promo-activate" id="active_promocod">Активировать промокод</button>

    <div class="result">
        <span id="answer"> <div class="messages_promo"></div> </span>
        <span class="loader hidden"><img src="img/loader.gif" alt=""></span>
    </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Далее, пишу скрипт, отправляю в файл controllPromocod.php для проверки, есть ли этот промокод в системе или нет. Вот тут мне не очень нравится, как я все это пишу, кажется так все громоздко.

```
<script>

        $('#active_promocod').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); /* дальше ваш код */ 
          var promocod=$('#promocod').val();
          $.ajax({
                    url: "../controllPromocod.php", // куда отправляем
                    type: "post", // метод передачи
                    dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
                    data: { // что отправляем
                        "promocod": promocod
                    },
                    // после получения ответа сервера
                   success: function(data) {

                    $('.messages_promo').html(data.result); // выводим ответ сервера,но он не выводится
                    }

                });

        });
</script>
```

Далее в файле php идет проверка

```
$promocod = $_POST['promocod'];
    $msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы

     if(isset($promocod) AND !empty($promocod))
     {  
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM CRM_PARTNERS WHERE promocod='".$promocod."'";
            $r = mysqli_query($mysql,$SQL);
            if(!$r) exit(mysqli_error($mysql));
            $hk=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

            if (isset($hk['promocod']) AND !empty($hk['promocod']))
                {

                // собираем данные из формы
                $message .= "Промокод: " . $_POST['promocod']. "<br/>";  
                $message .= "Дата и время (MSC): " . date("d.m.y H:i"); 
                send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
                $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>Промокод активирон!</span>";

                unset($_SESSION["name"]);
                unset($_SESSION["phone"]);
                $_SESSION['promocod'] =$hk['promocod'];
                $_SESSION['sale'] =$hk['sale'];
                }
            else 
                {
                $message="Промокода нет в системе";
                $msg_box_text = "Промокода нет в системе";

                $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$msg_box_text</span><br/>";
                $_SESSION['promocod'] =1;
                send_mail($message); // отправим письмо

                }

    }



    echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => $msg_box
    ));

        function send_mail($message){
            // почта, на которую придет письмо
            $mail_to = "79174844812@ya.ru"; 
            // тема письма
            $subject = "Промокод";

            // заголовок письма
            $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
            $headers .= "From: Тестовое письмо <no-reply@test.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо

            // отправляем письмо 
            mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
      var_dump($_SESSION);
```

В этом php файле отправляется  'result' => $msg_box, он ведь в любом случае должен быть, так как задается и в if и в else, а у меня пусто.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю, не понимаю.... `<div class="messages_promo">`ЗДЕСЬ ОЖИДАЮ ОТВЕТ, а его НЕТ((

Comment: Страница без перезагрузки

Comment: Неужели тяжело открыть инструменты разработчика в браузере, посмотреть  что приходит от сервера (и приходит ли)? Жахнуть `console.log(somevar);` наконец-то! Но проблема в том, что сервер отдаёт не json, а текст

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pgkn9y в инструментах вижу, что ответ есть - он правильный, но как его вывести в между тегами div. Вот в чем вопрос

Comment: Вы всё смешали в кучу, и HTML-разметку, и возвращаемые данные. Если Вы используете AJAX, то (как правило) с сервера должен приходить JSON ответ, который Вы и используете дальше. Выведите в консоль ответ сервера и скажите, что Вы там видите: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: Здесь вы найдете полное руководство по работе с [jQuery + Ajax + JSON + PHP](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-11-11-jquery-ajax-json-php.html)